# Kotlin predefined code style synchronisation with oficial guide

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, kotlin, code-standards

I found [excellent guide](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/code-style-migration-guide.html#migration-to-a-new-code-style) how to apply **predefined** code style from official site.

[image: Apply code style]

But I can't found any information about how to **automatically** keep this setting up to date. For note, [coding convention page](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coding-conventions.html#coding-conventions) was updated [16 times in 2018 year](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-web-site/commits/master/pages/docs/reference/coding-conventions.md).
May be I already obtain this updates with new version of Android Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updates to the coding conventions page are clarifications to the text, not changes in the way code is supposed to be formatted. None of them require any updates to IDE settings.

Comment: Ok, Dmitry, but if changes happen? It will be updated automatically on my work station?

Comment: There are no changes planned. I cannot say what will happen if something which is not planned happens.